# Loop end determination processing of textillate.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-plugins

**I want to change the effect every time I finish the loop.**

・Therefore, I would like to first implement loop end judgment processing

**Therefore, every time I finish the loop, I want to display an alert**

・I created the following code but failed

· I want to display an alert every time I exit the loop, but in reality I only see the alert once

```
<div class="hoge">
  <ul class="texts" style="display: none">
    <li>string1</li>
    <li>string2</li>
  </ul>
</div>

var effectAry=['flash','bounce','shake','tada','swing','wobble'];
var data = {
  loop: true,
  in: {'effect':effectAry[0]},
  out: {'effect':effectAry[1]}
};
$('.hoge').textillate(data);
$('.hoge').on('start.tlt', console.log('-----start.tlt triggered.'))
.on('inAnimationBegin.tlt', console.log('inAnimationBegin.tlt triggered.'))
.on('inAnimationEnd.tlt', console.log('inAnimationEnd.tlt triggered.'))
.on('outAnimationBegin.tlt', console.log('outAnimationBegin.tlt triggered.'))
.on('outAnimationEnd.tlt', console.log('outAnimationEnd.tlt triggered.'))
.on('end.tlt', alert('-----★end.tlt'));
```

---

[Events](https://github.com/jschr/textillate)

> Textillate triggers the following events:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, make sure you are importing all dependencies (jquery + animate css + littering js) and use out.callback method for ending function.

Edited:

```js
var effectAry = ['flash', 'bounce', 'shake', 'tada', 'swing', 'wobble'];
var data = {
  loop: true,
  in: {
    effect: effectAry[0]
  },
  out: {
    effect: effectAry[1],
    callback: function(){
      alert('-----★end.tlt')
    }
  },
};
$('.hoge').textillate(data);
$('.hoge').on('start.tlt', console.log('-----start.tlt triggered.'))
.on('inAnimationBegin.tlt', console.log('inAnimationBegin.tlt triggered.'))
.on('inAnimationEnd.tlt', console.log('inAnimationEnd.tlt triggered.'))
.on('outAnimationBegin.tlt', console.log('outAnimationBegin.tlt triggered.'))
.on('outAnimationEnd.tlt', console.log('outAnimationEnd.tlt triggered.'));
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/downloads/davatron5000/Lettering.js/jquery.lettering-0.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/textillate/0.4.0/jquery.textillate.js"></script>
<div class="hoge">
  <ul class="texts" style="display: none">
    <li>string1</li>
    <li>string2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```